# Is there a design pattern that can deal with method call dependencies?

Tags: c++, design-patterns

My problem is like this:

When you design a c++ class, in some cases, some methods can only be called after some other methods have been called, or after some data member has been properly prepared.

I found it quite hard to deal with when there are some data member dependencies that is often not so obvious, and the class needs to be extended to support more features and functionalities. It is really error-prone.

Execution speed of the code is not important in my case, code clarity/maintainability/sensibility is more important.

Comment: A common way to handle such things is by using boolean flags that is checked. But perhaps a better solution might be a design that doesn't mandate such ordering?

Comment: It is hard to address this problem without a context / concrete example. Could you provide one?

Comment: This question is off topic here, as you have no code to show us. However, it is a perfect candidate for https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This sounds like a [design smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_smell).

I think that you need to reconsider your classes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it leads to boilerplate code. Inf fact it's [procedural programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procedural_programming) which has been replaced by OOP in 1970th

Comment: @Mawg when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me. I will be sure to do so in future.

Answer (score 1):

If `method2` could be called only after `method1` then class has a state. You want to keep state consistent and methods which could change/use this state should not damage the state.

So you need incapsulation. Incapsulation is not about how to make field a private and create `setField()` method but about who could change the state. The right answer: only object could change its state. If you have setters for every single field you have an unprotected object and control about consistent state has leaked.

In practice, you could re-desing code so data could be set up during previous steps only. In this case you don't worry about checking "is data prepared?" each time `method2` called.

To avoid untimely calls there are several approaches. Each has pro and contras. I suppose you have chain of state0 -> method1 -> state1 -> method2 -> state2 -> method3 -> state3

- Throw an exception if object has different state. F.e. inside method1 add 
  `if currentState.differs(state0) throw exception`
  Most easy to implement, this way won't help you in terms of understanding and maintaining your project
- Use combination of [State](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) and  [Chain-of-responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern. Divide class in several ones and each could accept previous one as input param and return next class in chain. F.e. Class0 would have method wih signature `Class1 method1(state0)`, Class1 have `Class2 method2(class1)` and Class 2 have `state3 method3(class2)`. So nobody could call `Class2.method3` or `method1(class3)` - it will not compile. As a side effect you get a lot of classes. Also you could get rigid process flow but it could be more flexible than next option.
- Use [Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern. Create a `Processor` class with `process` method and make sure only this class could call desired methods.
  `state3 process(state0) {
  prepareStuff();
  state1 = method1(state0)
  somePreparation(state1)
  state2 = method2(state1)
  anotherPrepare(state2)
  return method3(state2)
  }`
  Then you could alter process flow by subclassing `Processor` and overriding preparation methods. Nobody could override `process()`. The disadvantage is you **always** get the whole process and can't stop after method2 (In fact you can but it would lead to *leak* the state and you get again uncontrolable process)
  Also note [policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design) template

In some sense both ways incapsulate the state of process at a higher level.

---

There are another ways to implement call dependency. No matter what you choose you have to **strictly limit** possibility to call methods anywhere at random moment.

Comment: Your second point would be more [State_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) than [Chain-of-responsibility_pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern).And that would be my preferred method.

Comment: @Jarod42 good point, I don't know about that pattern. Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You may consider adding an enum `state` variable to record the state of your object, and handle state checking and transitions in methods that need to be called sequencially.
And if the state becomes too complex you should consider revising your class design and perhaps split it into smaller classes.